# Export XMLElements with MathML contents

Tags: export, string-manipulation, xml

#### Setup

Here's my mathML expression:

```
mathML = ExportString[1/2, "MathML"]
```

> ```
> "<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
>  <mfrac>
>   <mn>1</mn>
>   <mn>2</mn>
>  </mfrac>
> </math>"
> ```

and an `XMLElement`:

```
xml = XMLElement["tag", {}, {"data", mathML}]
```

#### Task and the problem

which I'd like to `Export(String)` without manipulating mathMLcontents but it converts some symbols:

```
ExportString[xml, "XML"] 

"<tag>data&lt;math \
xmlns=&apos;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&apos;&gt;
 &lt;mfrac&gt;
  &lt;mn&gt;1&lt;/mn&gt;
  &lt;mn&gt;2&lt;/mn&gt;
 &lt;/mfrac&gt;
&lt;/math&gt;</tag>"
```

#### Expected result:

while I'd like to get:

```
"<tag>data<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
 <mfrac>
  <mn>1</mn>
  <mn>2</mn>
 </mfrac>
</math></tag>"
```

---

#### Solution(?)

I can get this with

```
ExportString[xml, "XML",  "Entities" -> {"<" -> "<", ">" -> ">", "'" ->"'"}]
```

but is this the right approach? If not, can I restrict this to only MathML expressions somehow?

#### A problem with solution:

The problem is that if those symbols are somewhere outside MathML expression, the resulting XML document will have incorrect structure:

```
ExportString[
  XMLElement["tag", {}, {"1 > 2"}], 
  "XML", 
  "Entities" -> {"<" -> "<", ">" -> ">", "'" -> "'"}
]
```

> ```
> "<tag>1 > 2</tag>"
> ```

I suppose it is not acceptable. I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit, I hit upon a solution involving a round-trip through the import/export subsystem. First, it is helpful to have everything in the same representation, so we need to put the mathml into `XMLElement` form, e.g.

```
mathml = ImportString[ExportString[1/2, "MathML"],
 {"MathML", "XMLElement"}]
(*
 XMLElement["math", {"xmlns" -> "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"}, 
 {XMLElement["mfrac", {}, {XMLElement["mn", {}, {"1"}], 
   XMLElement["mn", {}, {"2"}]}]}]
*)
```

Then, you can combine them as you wish,

```
xml = XMLElement["tag", {}, {"data", mathml}]
(*
 XMLElement["tag", {}, {"data", 
  XMLElement["math", {"xmlns" -> "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"}, 
   {XMLElement["mfrac", {}, {XMLElement["mn", {}, {"1"}], 
  XMLElement["mn", {}, {"2"}]}]}]}]
*)
```

and when exported

```
ExportString[xml, "XML"]
(* "<tag>
 data<mathxmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac>
 </math></tag>"
*)
```

Note, it appears to lose formatting, and initially I was under the impression that the text could not be a sibling to an xml element, but re-reading the [xml spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#syntax), implies that it is, instead, being treated as an inline element.

Comment: I get no error on 10.2 in Windows with `ExportString[
   XMLElement[
    "tag", {}, {"data", 
     ImportString[
      ExportString[#, "MathML"], {"MathML", "XMLElement"}]}], 
   "XML"] &@(1/2)`. It produces nicely `<tag>data<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac></math></tag>`

Comment: @RolfMertig look closer, the mathml is being interpreted as a string. If it were being interpreted as xml, it would be formatted differently.

Comment: but the result is like like "Expected result" ,or?

Comment: @RolfMertig looking through the [xml spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#syntax) now (it's been over a decade since I've read it), and it looks like I may be incorrect: "Text consists of intermingled character data and markup." So, likely the mathml is being treated as inline markup. Will update my answer.